# How to about nesting a variable amount of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch a number from the user and based on said number i want to nest that amount of dictionaries within the overall dictionary. Bellow is a snippet of my code.

```
pizzas = ""
pizza = ""
base = ""
ptype = ""
size = ""
order = {
    "pizzas":{
        "pizza":{
            "base":base,
            "type":ptype,
            "size":size
        }
    }
}

pizzaNumber = int(input("How many pizzas would you like to order? "))
x=0
while(x<pizzaNumber):
    print("Details for Pizza #"+str(x+1))
    pizza += "pizza"+str(x)
    base = input("Base (hand tossed, thin crust, regular)? ")
    ptype = input("Type (pepperoni, cheese, veggie lovers hawaiian)? ")
    size = input("Size (small, medium, large)? ")
    
    pizza = {
        "base":base,
        "type":ptype,
        "size":size
    }
    order["pizzas"] = pizza

    x=x+1

print(order)
```

I am not concerned with efficiency at the moment, I am just lost on how to go about this in general. If my explanation was not enough please feel free to as a question.

I believe using a dictionary is required because i have to calculate the cost based on the size of each pizza.

Comment: Use a list of dicts. The list may have one element.

Comment: hi, perhaps keep a variable pointing to the current dict, and assign it to a new inner dict at each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it concise and readable would be the job 1. It will make it easier for you to transform it. For your task you can opt in for a readable yet concise dictionary comprehension. Made by f strings and looped in till your desired limit:

```
pizzaNumber = int(input("How many pizzas would you like to order? "))
order = {'pizzas':{f'pizza{num+1}': {
        "base":input("Base (hand tossed, thin crust, regular)? "),
        "type":input("Type (pepperoni, cheese, veggie lovers hawaiian)? "),
        "size":input("Size (small, medium, large)? ")} for num in range(pizzaNumber)}}

print(order)
```

Outputs in:

```
{'pizzas': {'pizza1': {'base': 'thin', 'type': 'pepp', 'size': 'XL'},
  'pizza2': {'base': 'Hand tossed', 'type': 'chees', 'size': 'Med'},
  'pizza3': {'base': 'Reg', 'type': 'Veg', 'size': 'Small'}}}
```

Now its a `dict` ad you can add values to this dict as `order['something_besides_pizza'] = 'whatever you like'`

Answer (score 0):

A list could be more appropriate for the 'order'.
You could do it like this:

```
pizzas = ""
pizza = ""
base = ""
ptype = ""
size = ""
order = []


pizzaNumber = int(input("How many pizzas would you like to order? "))
x=0
while(x<pizzaNumber):
    print("Details for Pizza #"+str(x+1))
    pizza = "pizza"+str(x)
    base = input("Base (hand tossed, thin crust, regular)? ")
    ptype = input("Type (pepperoni, cheese, veggie lovers hawaiian)? ")
    size = input("Size (small, medium, large)? ")
    
    pizza = {
        "base":base,
        "type":ptype,
        "size":size
    }
    order.append(pizza)

    x=x+1

print(order)
```

The output would be like this :

```
[{'base': 'a', 'type': 'z', 'size': 'e'}, {'base': 'q', 'type': 's', 'size': 'd'}]
```

Comment: I believe using a dictionary is required in this scenario, i have edited my original post